# Bitcoin Cash full node

Tags: bitcoin-cash

Whats bitcoin cash is it a description on how BCH/BCC should run ?

I need a full node BCH/BCC If I run bitcoin ABC or UNLIMITED will I get the bitcoin cash blocks ?

or are there difference in blocks between ABC and UNLIMITED

Comment: "should I run bitcoin ABC/ UNLIMITED" Just choose one. We're not allowed to answer opinion based questions.

Comment: Sorry about that I have changed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin ABC, Bitcoin Unlimited Cash, and Bitcoin XT are Bitcoin Cash node clients. They do the same job, and the most important difference among them is their developers: They are developed by three independent development teams.

Some other differences:

- Bitcoin ABC uses Compact Blocks, Bitcoin Unlimited uses XThin, Bitcoin XT uses both Compact Blocks and XThin to download new blocks.
- 94% of the nodes are Bitcoin ABC, more than 5% of the nodes are Bitcoin Unlimited, and only a few (1-5) nodes are Bitcoin XT.

**Update:** It was 94% when this answer was written (when edited, there are more BU nodes!). You can see the live statistics [here](https://cashnodes.bitcoinunlimited.info/)

Other than their brands and those ^ differences, they're all the same.

If you really want to help the network, I'd suggest to run XT or Unlimited, because if a node crashing bug was found in Bitcoin ABC, it'd affect 90% of the network. If the network was 33% Bitcoin ABC, 33% Bitcoin Unlimited and 33% Bitcoin XT, then no such bug would be important that much, and the network would be more decentralized.