# What is the difference from Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Cash ABC? Its so confusing for noobs

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I haven't been following the silly bitcoin cash fiasco, but I see on coinmarketcap:

Bitcoin Cash ABC
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash-abc/

Bitcoin Cash
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash/

What is the difference? And what is the latest news with this silly coin as of today?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Bitcoin.

Comment: @G.Maxwell The [Help center](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says you can ask about *"- a cryptocurrency or technology derived directly from Bitcoin such as Namecoin or Litecoin. 
- distributed cryptocurrencies not derived directly from Bitcoin such as Ripple, Ethereum or NXT"*. Moreover, bitcoin.stackechange has [382 Questions tagged "Bitcoin-Cash"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin-cash)

Comment: There are separate stack exchanges for other cryptocurrencies.  To the extent that a question is generic or is otherwise of general researchy interest that's great. But altcoin specific stuff is frequently highly toxic and is often a pure waste of time and attention.

Comment: @G. Maxwell I agree with that personally, but as long as the site's help text explicitly allows these things, it seems unfair to downvote questions because of it. I've been seeing increasingly more comments/downvotes in this direction, so perhaps we should discuss on meta to change the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoin Cash full node](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70897/bitcoin-cash-full-node)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **What is the difference?**

Your second [link](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash/) says

> In order to reflect the current market, we have merged our Bitcoin Cash (BCH) and Bitcoin Cash ABC (BCHABC) listings. We have observed that a majority of exchanges are using the Bitcoin Cash (BCH) to refer to the Bitcoin Cash ABC implementation. For more information on Bitcoin Cash SV (BCHSV), please [navigate here](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash-sv/).

Your first link seems to be historical data only.

---

Footnote:

> **what is the latest news with this silly coin as of today?**

That is probably [off-topic here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).